# using List.collect f#

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming

I am trying to define a function which takes two lists and combines them using List.collect.

```
let concat xs xs' = 
    let concatList =  List.collect xs xs'
    printfn "%A" concatList

concat [1;2;3;4] [5;6;7;8]
```

I get the error message: 
FS0001: This expression was expected to have type ''a-> 'b list'
but here has type ''c list'

I read that this might be due to missing parameters, but I am unsure about this.

EDIT:

So I kinda got it to work like this:

```
 let concat xs xs' = 
    let concatList =  List.collect (fun x -> xs @ xs') xs
    printfn "%A" concatList

concat [1;2;3;4] [5;6;7;8]
```

But the output is: [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 1 ;2 ;3 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 1 ;2 ;3 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 1 ;2 ;3 4; 5; 6; 7; 8;]

Only wanted it to be [1 ;2 ;3 4; 5; 6; 7; 8;]
Any ideas why it runs so many times?

EDIT 2:

So I got it working like this:

```
let concat xs xs' = 
    let combList = [[xs];[xs']]
    let concatList =  List.collect id combList
    printfn "%A" concatList

concat [1;2;3;4] [5;6;7;8]
```

Comment: That is not what `List.collect` does. Did you mean `List.concat`?

Comment: I thought List.concat would make more sense. But am told not to use it.
Read about List.collect and it states:

"For each element of the list, applies the given function. Concatenates all the results and returns the combined list."

Comment: So what's the problem then?

Comment: It doesn't work. I get the error code. But shouldn't this work?

Comment: The description that you posted says "applies the given function". Where are you giving a function?

Comment: Also, if your question is about homework, you should indicate that in the question. Otherwise the people answering don't have the right context.

Comment: I added the fun keyword, but now the output is just wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125579/discussion-between-kthonenice-and-fyodor-soikin).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you noted in the comments, `List.collect` applies a function to each element of a list. Afterwards, it **concatenates the results** and returns a combined list. This second behavior is what will allow you to produce behavior similar to `List.concat`.

What do we need to do to achieve this?

Let's try looking at the documentation example:

```
let list1 = [10; 20; 30]
let collectList = List.collect (fun x -> [for i in 1..3 -> x * i]) list1
printfn "%A" collectList
//Output
//[10; 20; 30; 20; 40; 60; 30; 60; 90]
```

What's happening in this example is that for every element of `list1`, we are applying the function `(fun x -> [for i in 1..3 -> x * i])`. This gives us the same result as if we had used `List.map`. The result is `[[10; 20; 30]; [20; 40; 60]; [30; 60; 90]]`, which is then concatenated by `List.collect` into the final result above.

Now as to your problem, lets consider a related problem. Let's say we are given a list of lists such as

```
let x = [[10; 20; 30]; [20; 40; 60]; [30; 60; 90]]
```

How do we use `List.collect` to concatenate them to get the output 
`[10; 20; 30; 20; 40; 60; 30; 60; 90]`?

So, `List.collect` requires a function and a list. We can pass in the list of lists defined above, `x`, but we still need a function that will do a map. However, we don't really want to do any transformations of the elements of `x` we just want to use them as is, which means we should use `id`. Then using

```
List.collect id x
```

will return the desired result. Your specific problem is very similar to the problem above and should not be too difficult to solve.

Comment: let concat xs xs' = 
    let combList = xs @ xs'
    let concatList =  List.collect id combList
    printfn "%A" concatList

concat [1;2;3;4] [5;6;7;8]

So something like this should work?

Comment: Using the id keyword made it work if i just took the parameters and added let combList. 
I would never use the .collect this way, so seems weird I am told to. 
Thanks for the id suggestion.

Comment: id is just a convenience function for `fun i -> i`